# A gull and a crow attacked the peace doves released by the Pope. What is Christian interpretation?

Tags: catholicism, eastern-orthodox, signs

In 2014 pope Francis released two doves of peace to signify reconcilation in Ukraine. Yet, they were instantly attacked by two birds, one by a gull, the other by a crow and lost the feathers in the sight of thousands of Romans.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMH810BAM7I

How do (Catholic) Christians interpret this event? Is it a divine sign?

Comment: Catholics don't have any official interpretations of this sort of thing; and any unofficial interpretation would be purely a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 5):

From the Point of View of Roman Catholic Church teaching, [divination is not an appropriate response to natural phenomena](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/__P7E.HTM).  You would thus not get an official interpretation of such an event.

To answer your subordinate question: per the RCC, *no, it is not a divine sign*.

[From the Catechism](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/__P7E.HTM)

> Divination and magic
>
> 2116 **All forms of divination are to be rejected:** recourse to Satan or
>   demons, conjuring up the dead or other practices falsely supposed to
>   "unveil" the future.48 Consulting horoscopes, astrology, palm reading,
>   **interpretation of omens** and lots, the phenomena of clairvoyance, and
>   recourse to mediums all conceal a desire for power over time, history,
>   and, in the last analysis, other human beings, as well as a wish to
>   conciliate hidden powers. They contradict the honor, respect, and
>   loving fear that we owe to God alone.